# Создание объекта в PHP и переменные переменных

Tags: php

Привет.Есть 2 вопроса.

1. Можно создавать объект без использования `new class`? В javascript - `obj={}` или `obj=new Object()`. Что аналогичное есть в php?
2. Можно в пару словах показать и объяснить переменные переменных `$$var`? Как можно управлять динамически именами переменных.

Пока все. Всем спасибо за помощь.

Comment: 1.

    $obj = new stdClass();
    $obj->test = 'done';
    echo $obj->test; // -> done

2. по моему в [доках](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.variables.variable.php) этот вопрос прекрасно расписан

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Можно, но обращаться можно только к методам класса `className::methodName`, к переменным нет!
2. К вопросу 2 пример:

```
function hello($var)
{   
    $array = array
    (
        'name' => 'John',
        'surname' => 'Doe',
    );

extract($array);
return $$var;
}

echo hello('name'), hello('surname');
```

Answer (score 1):

1. [Объекты](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/language.oop5.php)
2. [Переменные переменных](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/language.variables.variable.php)